# Reference to assertEquals is ambiguous when running a unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

In my application

```
`CategoryDao` is a `interface`, `Category` is a model `class`
```

My code is

```
CategoryTestCase.java

package com.binod.onlineshopping.category.test;
import com.binod.onlineshopping.category.dao.CategoryDao;
import com.binod.onlineshopping.category.model.Category;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.AssertJUnit.assertEquals;

/**
 * Created by binod on 7/13/17.
 */
public class CategoryTestCase {

    private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;
    private static CategoryDao categoryDao;
    private Category category;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {

        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.refresh();
        categoryDao = (CategoryDao) context.getBean("categoryDao");
    }

    @Test
    public void addCategory(){
        category=new Category();
        category.setCname("Television");
        category.setCdescription("TV is the product");
        category.setImageUrl("c_Tv.png");
     assertEquals("sucessfully inserted..",true,categoryDao.addCategory(category));
    }

}
```

The error is :

```
Error:(34, 6) java: reference to assertEquals is ambiguous
 both method assertEquals(java.lang.String,boolean,boolean) in org.testng.AssertJUnit and method assertEquals(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object) in org.testng.AssertJUnit match
```

I am trying to `junit` test in my `springmvc` with `hibernate` project.I am trying to test in my `insert` module.but it gives a above error.
I saw many tutorial and references but i am unable to handle that error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose `categoryDao.addCategory` have `Boolean` type. Am I right?

Comment: or... `assertTrue("successfully inserted", categoryDao.addCategory(category))`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When the compiler tries to bound a method invocation to one distinct method, if it doesn't manage to identify a method more specific than others, it emits a compilation error. It is your case.

> both method assertEquals(java.lang.String,boolean,boolean) in
> org.testng.AssertJUnit
>
> and method
> assertEquals(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object) in
> org.testng.AssertJUnit
>
> match

If you have this ambiguity problem at compile time, it means that you don't invoke the `assertEquals()` method with two primitive `boolean` as arguments.

So `categoryDao.addCategory(category)` returns very probably `Boolean` and not `boolean`.

**Boolean or boolean return ?**

Giving the possibility to return `null` (as `Boolean` allows it) makes sense only if you need to handle the `null` case. But an adding operation is either true or false.
 What a `null` could mean ?
So, I think that this should return `boolean`.
In this way, you code would compile fine as the method bound by the compiler would be without any ambiguity :

`assertEquals(java.lang.String,boolean,boolean)`.

**assertEquals() or assertTrue()?**

Besides, to assert if an expression is true, you may simply use `Assert.assertTrue()` method that is more explicit :

```
assertTrue("sucessfully inserted..", categoryDao.addCategory(category));
```

Comment: yeah assertTrue() should do the thing here.

Comment: 'Giving the possibility to return null (as Boolean allows it) ' - still helpful today!

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
assertEquals("sucessfully inserted..",true,categoryDao.addCategory(category));
```

with

```
assertEquals("sucessfully inserted..", Boolean.TRUE, categoryDao.addCategory(category));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on what `categoryDao.addCategory(category)` returns. Since you have used it to check the equality with `true`, which is a boolean value, it might return a primitive `boolean` or a Object wrapper `Boolean`.

i.e. 
you might be invoking it as,

```
assertEquals("sucessfully inserted..", true, true or false);
// with Primitive boolean values
```

or,

```
assertEquals("sucessfully inserted..", true, TRUE or FALSE);
// with Boolean values
```

check below two methods in `org.testng.AssertJUnit`,

> public static void assertEquals(String message,
>                                   Object expected,
>                                   Object actual)

and

> public static void assertEquals(String message,
>                                   boolean expected,
>                                   boolean actual)

So if your **third parameter is a primitive** **boolean** value there shouldn't be an ambiguity about which method to invoke (it clearly should be the first one).
But ***if it is not a prmitive boolean then there is an ambiguity*** about which method you are referring here.

Refer :

- https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.11-gd61e30c-133/javadoc/org/testng/AssertJUnit.html#assertEquals-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-
- https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.11-gd61e30c-133/javadoc/org/testng/AssertJUnit.html#assertEquals-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-